# Is there a module or way to edit all my product's categories from one admin menu?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ubercart

Currently I have to go to admin>store>products and then go to each product individually to change their category. This is tedious when you have hundreds of products and need to change many of their categories. For just changing the title/name of a category/term I can just edit the taxonomy term but Ive also added many new terms. So is there a module or a setting to allow this? I am using ubercart.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of possibilities:

1. Perhaps try [Views Bulk Operations](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) - this might have an operation for changing taxonomy term in content in a batch.
2. If you are changing the same taxonomy term (old) to another term (new) on many products, I wonder if deleting the new term and then renaming the old term to what that new term was would do the job? The end result is that you now have products all using the new term. This idea would only be suitable if there isn't other content using that new term which is not part of the change.

Comment: I'll give views bulk operations a shot, and as for the second suggestion, that'll work for some of my terms, but others are new. But that's definitely a good idea for the terms that I'm just changing. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, you might like - http://www.webomelette.com/how-batch-assign-taxonomy-terms-nodes-using-views-bulk-operations